# Getting values from Map given list of keys in Scala

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

Basically I need to get a set of values from a map for a keys in a given list (in the same order keys are given).

```
val kv = Map("k3" -> "v3", "k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2")
val ks = List("k1", "k2")
```

The best I could have improvised is `foldRight` over `ks`:

```
scala> (ks foldRight List[String]()) { (v, a) => kv(v) :: a }
res7: List[String] = List(v1, v2)
```

Are there any more convenient ways to do this in standard lib or just the shorter code, ideally something alike `kv getVals ks`? :)

Question is not so important of course, just trying to explore towards good style.

Comment: Wouldn't `foldLeft` be a better option here? It would be a better style I think, because it is implemented by iteration while foldRight is implemented by recursion in List.scala.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use flatMap:

```
 ks flatMap { k => kv get k }
```

Or better:

```
 ks flatMap (kv get)
```

And with `for` comprehensions:

```
for (k <- ks; v <- kv get k) yield v
```

But none are as succinct or as clear as your own one-liner: :-)

```
ks map kv
List("k42") map kv // will barf
```

However, note that this is exceptional - it may throw an exception if `ks` contains a key not defined in the map `kv`.

Answer (score 30):

Or:

```
ks collect kv
```

The result is composed of all the values of kv for which a key is in ks.

(Besides being a Function a Map is also a PartialFunction)

Comment: Great, `collect` happens to be safe variant when keys might be missing.

Comment: +1 I think this is as good as it gets. How blind was **I** to not exploit `Map` being a `PartialFunction`.